# How to setup lightdm to automatically log in specific user only once

Tags: linux, linux-mint, lightdm, autologin

When you add following config into one of the lightdm config file, you can get user to be automatically logged in:

```
autologin-user=user224348
autologin-user-timeout=20
user-session=ubuntu
```

This is useful for example if you have encrypted drive and don't want to type password twice (once to unlock drive, second time to log-in). Problem with this is that if you are on lock-screen, you can just choose to switch account and login back without providing password. One possible fix would be to set `allow-user-switching=False`, but that has it's own disadvantages.

**Is there a way to set-up light-dm in a way that specific user would get logged in when the system boots, but after that, password would be required?**

Closest thing I could find is that maybe it's possible to create own PAM module or use existing one, but I have no idea how that works.

I'm using Linux Mint 20.3.